# SQL server Business intelligence studio for front end

Tags: sql, sql-server, business-intelligence

My company are moving their databases from MS Access to SQL server. They have the SQL Server Business Intelligence  Studio 2012 version installed. I have one question? Before in MS Access we usually do entries to database manually but now switched to SQL Server Business Intelligence how will the entries of data  be possible? Can we make front end in B.I studio for the database? What other tools we required for front-end development?

Comment: BIDS is not the tool for this job. You can use linked tables in Access to connect to SQL Server - this might be preferential for you as there's less of a learning curve for end users.

Comment: ...slightly confused by this question  - when you mention BIDS are you talking about SSRS?

Comment: @user2558010 maybe take a look at InfoPath

Comment: Thanks, But what will be the best tools for front end while you have 70 tables in back end Sql server database.

Comment: There's no such thing as a SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio version. There's SQL Server, and then there's Business Intelligence Studio, which is a BI-specific development solution. If you are asking how you can perform data entry on your SQL Server data tables, you could use Visual Studio for that and develop a data entry application, either as a standalone (.exe) or a web-solution. Alternatively, like Gvee mentioned, linked tables in Access, if you're not familiar with application development. However, that might mean you'd not be able to set up a proper business logic layer.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! The comments above can help you to open the way you want but I want to add more.

First of all! If you want to make data entries then go for front end GUI! Develope GUIs in Visual Studio using Windows Form or WPF using C# or VB.NET.

Second! If you just want to load data from Source to destination, then use SSIS instead of GUIs. I am assuming that GUIs are for your use only not for client. If it is for your use then use Integration services and use them to load data in SQL Server.

BI Studio can be used to develop frond end but that is a hactic task and not recommended. And the reason is, there is a "Script Task" in SSIS which is a custom task and all C# code can be placed there and it will slow down the performance because it compiles every time and then runs.